# В чем разница между статической функцией и функцией указанной в классе (не метод класса с (self))

Tags: python, ооп

```
class Robot:
    def sayHi():
        print("Hi")

class Robot:
    @staticmethod
    def sayHi():
        print("Hi")
```

В чем разница ? При вызове `Robot.sayHi()` оба работают.

PS: понимаю, что вопрос глупый, но не удается найти ответ (вероятно не знаю как правильно задать вопрос)

Comment: Статическая функция относится к классу, а не к конкретному объекту. Соответственно, она не может пользоваться данными конкретного объекта, а также нестатическими функциями. Точнее, может, но она должна раздобыть себе для этого какой-то объект, в отличие от нестатической функции, которая может обращаться к данным и функциям объекта, у которого она вызвана. P. S.: Вопрос хороший.

Comment: Разница будет при вызове `Robot().sayHi()`

Comment: VladD, вероятно вам показалось, что там указан метод класса(self), а не просто функция в классе 
******
insolor, описанная выше ситуация
******
andreymal, благодарю пока это единственное обнаруженное различие

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оба приведенных примера определяют класс со статическим методом. Разница лишь в том, что во втором случае вы используете декоратор `@staticmethod`, который явно указывает, что метод статичный.

Когда у класса есть статические методы, логично предположить, что они будут вызваны "от класса", а не от объекта этого класса:

```
class Robot:
def sayHi():
    print("Hi")


Robot.sayHi()
```

Но если мы вызовем этот же метод от объекта:

```
robot = Robot()
robot.sayHi()
```

То получим ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../main.py", line 9, in <module>
    robot.sayHi()
TypeError: sayHi() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Почему так происходит?

Потому что вызов `robot.sayHi()` равносилен вызову `Robot.sayHi(robot)`, а поскольку данный метод ничего не принимает - возникает ошибка из-за передачи объекта класса неявным первым аргументом.

---

Отдельно стоит упомянуть о [@staticmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) из документации:

> A static method does not receive an implicit first argument. To
>   declare a static method, use this idiom:
>
> ```
> class C:
>     @staticmethod
>     def f(arg1, arg2, ...): ...
> ```
>
> The @staticmethod form is a function decorator – see the description of function definitions in Function
>   definitions for details.
>
> **It can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance
>   (such as C().f()). The instance is ignored except for its class.**
>
> Static methods in Python are similar to those found in Java or C++.
>   For a more advanced concept, see  classmethod() in this section.

Как видно из документации, данный декоратор "явно" делает метод статичным. Однако его все еще можно вызвать, используя объект: `robot().sayHi()`, но в этот раз никакой ошибки не будет и данный вызов будет равносилен `Robot.sayHi()` - учитывается только тип вызываемого объекта.